# Java program as Windows service with initialization phase

Tags: java, windows, service

Is there a way to start java program as Windows service **so that it is not started until it has initalized fully.**

For example Apache Commons Daemon has single start method which should not return. To Windows, it is either on or off, no initialization.

Then again if I create Windows service with Visual Studio template it implements ServiceBase that has method OnStart. That method works so that the service is reported 'started' only after the method has returned. Which is exactly what I need.

Comment: You could delay "OnStart" until your Service has initialized fully. But chances are that it is reported unresponsive. OnStart is urged to return as fast as possible. Is there a reason why it should not be reported as started until fully initialized? You could also provide means of caching requests until init phase is done or return some "initializing" error on which Client tries again later ... Plenty of possibilities.

Comment: Im working on making sure our legacy java (corba)services start up correctly. The services are very dependant on the order of startup and next one should not be started before the first one is started. There are 2 services that start up random amount of time (~1-3minutes). If this is not possible, i will have to make it in another way, this was the simplest way i could think of but couldnt find a way to do it for java services.

Comment: Hm, ... it is possible to "start delayed" and to create dependency-structures with Windows Services. Not sure whether it is possible to combine the two? But still, you could only wait like 3 minutes or so but still you could not be sure the service has started "under the hood". Maybe it would make sense to write some kind of Startup-Manager that is able to check the (real internal) status of the services and start them appropriately?